# System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. C#

Tags: .net, using, filestreamresult

### FileController.cs

```
public IActionResult GetFileByName(string name)
  {
    return _file.GetFile(name);
  }
```

### FileRepository.cs

```
  public FileStreamResult GetFile(string name)
  {
  
    string path = "C:\\"
    FileInfo fileInfo = new fileInfo(path);
    using FileStream fileStream = fileInfo.Open(FileMode.Open);
    return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/pdf")
                {
                    FileDownloadName = "bill.pdf"
                };
}
```

////In Response exception message ###System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.

Comment: `using` causes `Dispose` to be called when the end of scope for that variable is reached.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why a `FileStreamResult` when you have a file path? The *correct* way would be to return a ``PhysicalFileResult` with the absolute file path you want to return